# Joomla - wrapper | is there any disadvantage?

Tags: iframe, joomla, wrapper

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and I need to create a simple gallery in my site but I don't want to create new component because it's takes a lot of time to learn...

So I wanted to ask:
if I create a simple jQuery gallery in standalone .html file and then I embed it using Wrapper into Joomla, will there be any heavy problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do a full-blown MVC component for this: a quick one will work. Add the file `components/com_jquery_gallery/jquery_gallery.php` and add your HTML code there. The HTML will be accessible through `index.php?option=com_jquery_gallery`.

Comment: thanks for reply, this is new for me, I didn't know I can build a component in this easy way, without MVC.
But Sorcerer plugin suggested below will probably work well.. I will try both ways

Answer (score 1):

Joomla Wrapper is essentially an IFRAME. If your gallery works in an IFRAME without any issues, and you're completely happy with updating the embedded HTML file manually, then the only downside is that it is a usability "hack", and it may make it more difficult to manage it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper is very limited and you could use a "custom" code plugin instead of the wrapper, which allows you to place html, javascript, PHP into an article, IMO it's better than the wrapper because it gives more control.

I recommend [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5051) It's great and was updated yesterday :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try it, it looks as the best and the easiest solution

Comment: @simPod if you found this the best solution, please accept it by checking the mark next to it :)

Comment: not yet. My project is stucked on another thing. Just wait ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use one of the many free photo gallery extensions??

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery

No code work, plenty of features, and much faster than even the simplest component.